# How to get Ruby hash to remove braces in output

Tags: ruby, hash, rspec, output, square-bracket

I started working through some sample problems on Test-First, and had worked out a solution which passed all the RSpec tests using Ruby 1.8.7. I just upgraded my OS, and Ruby upgraded as well; my code no longer passes the RSpec test. Can anyone help me understand why this is not working anymore?

#### My code

```
  def entries 
    @d
  end
```

#### the error message

Failures:

1) Dictionary can add whole entries with keyword and definition

```
Failure/Error: @d.entries.should == {'fish' => 'aquatic animal'}
   expected: {"fish"=>"aquatic animal"}
        got: {["fish"]=>["aquatic animal"]} (using ==)
```

Diff:

```
 @@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
   -"fish" => "aquatic animal"
   +["fish"] => ["aquatic animal"]
```

### #

I can't figure out what to change about the formatting. (One of the RSpec tests is that the @d must be empty when created, so when I try modifying the @d by putting in explicit formatting it also fails, but I'm imagining that there's a straightforward type issue here I'm not understanding.)

**Update:** More code

```
class Dictionary
  def initialize d = {}
    @d = d
  end

  def entries
    @d
  end

  def keywords
    @d.keys.sort
  end

  def add words
    n_key = words.keys
    n_val = words.values
    @d[n_key] = n_val
  end
end
```

Comment: Why does `@d` have an `@d` property? What you're missing here is the dictionary insertion code. Also if your Ruby just upgraded to 1.8.7, you're way behind. The current version is 2.1.1 and [1.8.7 has been retired](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2013/06/30/we-retire-1-8-7/).

Comment: Sorry! I didn't post all my code because I didn't want to clutter things up. This is my full code (at least up to that point).

Comment: class Dictionary

  def initialize d = {}
    @d = d
  end
  
  def entries 
    @d
  end
  
  def keywords
    @d.keys.sort
  end
  
  def add words
    n_key = words.keys
    n_val = words.values
    @d[n_key] = n_val
  end end

Comment: It's best to edit your question and add the code to it.

Comment: This is my first time posting to this forum; I don't quite understand how to format things. I tried to paste my code into the comment above; I'll try to put it in the original post.

Comment: Generally the `{ }` button will automatically format code for you. Select the text you want to format and click it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to do some kind of mass assignment by adding several words at once, but that's not the way to do it.

A Ruby Hash can have *anything* as a key, and this includes arrays of things. It's not like JavaScript where it will automatically cast to string, or other languages that have the same sort of conversion to a specific dictionary key type. In Ruby any object will do.

So your add words method should be:

```
def add words
  words.each do |word, value|
    @d[word] = value
  end
end
```

As a note using names like `@d` is really bad form. Try and be more specific about what that is, or you risk confusing people endlessly. Programs filled with things like `@d`, `x` and `S` are awful to debug and maintain. Better to be clear if a bit verbose than terse and ambiguous.

Secondly, it's not clear how your `Dictionary` class is all that different from `Hash` itself. Maybe you could make it a subclass and save yourself some trouble. For example:

```
class Dictionary < Hash
  def keywords
    keys.sort
  end

  def add words
    merge!(words)
  end
end
```

In general terms it's always best to use the core Ruby classes to do what you want, then build out from there. Re-inventing the wheel leads to incompatibility and frustration. The built-in Hash class has a whole bunch of utility methods that are very handy for doing data transformation, conversion and iteration, things you're losing by creating your own opaque wrapper class.

The [`merge!`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-i-merge-21) method in particular adds data to an existing Hash, which is exactly what you want.

Comment: Oh wow, thank you for the detailed response! I used @d because the RSpec test had done it. I've changed that. I actually had the same method you put for "add" before, and it worked, but since I upgraded to Mavericks it gave me an error saying that .each was undefined for words. I couldn't figure out how to fix that.

Comment: I'm not sure how the OS version has any impact on that. That mostly depends on the Ruby version (`ruby -v` will tell you) and what you're sending in to `add`.